# How to add background color to Highcharts while PDF export

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, highcharts

I have to add the background color to highcharts graphs when it is downloaded,here is the code I have added.

```
           chart: {
                    renderTo: container,
                    type: 'columnrange',
                    inverted: true,
                    plotBackgroundColor: '#e9e9e9',
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    height: 50,
                    width: analyticsAngular.element('#' + container)[0].clientWidth,
                    spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
                }
```

Even though I added the backgroundColor it is not coming in the pdf.Can nayone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user11917666, Could you describe the problem more precisely? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h92bpfq6/ everything works as expected.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I am not getting the backgrouncolor to my graph

Comment: Could you reproduce that in jsfiddle? In the example that I have provided, the color is changed.